# Can we intercept js request in Angular?

Tags: angular, interceptor

I have written http interceptor in angular but I cannot see js request coming in the interceptor handler. I wanted to intercept the some js request and do some handling around it.
I am looking to intercept request like
`Request URL: http://localhost:5000/chunk1.js`

```
@Injectable()
export class SimpleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req); // js request is not coming here.
  }
}
```

Let me know if there is something else to intercept js request?

Note: I am working on angular lazy-loading and want to intercept the chunk loading request and change the host of request.

Comment: The interceptor will only intercept requests executed with `httpClient`.

Comment: ok.
@MatthieuRiegler then how can I intercept the request for js file?
I am working on angular lazy loading and want to intercept the chunk loading request and change the host of request? how can this be done?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler
I have done lazy loading in my angular web component. but when I use this web component in any parent angular application the request for lazy-loaded modules request goes from the parent application. I want to change this to make request from where web component assets are hosted.
like parent application is hosted on http://localhost:3443 and webcomponent assets are hosted at http://localhost:5000
so when the lazy-loaded modules request is going it is from localhost:3443 I want to make it from localhost:5000

Answer (score 3):

Interceptors need to be registered as providers in app module.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
  providers:    [ 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyHttpInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And as @Matthieu wrote, just if you will use httpclient to triger calls will work.

Comment: I'm not sur the interceptor will catch the lazy loaded modules request.

Comment: Can you detail the use case for which you want to do that, maybe we can come up with a solution, other then intercepting those calls?

Comment: @ZsoltB
I want to change the host of lazy loaded modules request
for eg: if default lazy loaded modules request is http://localhost:5000/chunk1.js I want to change this to http://localhost:5001/chunk1.js

Comment: For this scenario, you could use a proxy, something like Fiddler as standalone, or if you want some more intrusive you could try with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-proxy

Answer (score 0):

The only way to intercept all requests is in the ServiceWorker with the fetch listener.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
   const url = event.request.url;
   // do what you need 
})
```